# Absolute convergence does not imply convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

Find a space and a series that converges absolutely but it does not converges.
It is clear that the space can't complete or Banach.

Comment: Well, does the space have to be a vector space? Otherwise, take $\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^k \left(\frac12\right)^n$ in $\Bbb R-\{\frac23\}$. Dumb, I know.

Comment: @TedShifrin I believe there's a typo in that expression: you want to replace $n$ with $k$.

Comment: Or perhaps take the sequence $s_N = -\sum_{n = 0}^N {1 \over 2^n}$ in $\mathbb R \setminus \{-2\}$. Then the absolute value converges to $2$ but $s_N \to -2$ which is not in the space.

Answer (score 3):

You can take $X$ to be the vector space of polynomials on the unit circle $\mathbb T$, with the supremum norm. Now consider the series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n}.
$$
The series converges absolutely, because $|x|=1$, and you get a numerical series that converges in $\mathbb C$. But the series cannot converge in $X$, because it would have to be $\frac x {2-x}$, which is not a polynomial.

Comment: I think you meant that it would have to be $\frac{2}{2-x}$ and not $\frac{2}{1-x}$.

Comment: It's actually $x/(2-x)$, as the series starts at $n=1$. Edited.

Answer (score 1):

The taylor series expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ is 
$$1+a_1x-a_2x^2+a_3x^3+\cdots,$$
or
$$1+\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_nx^n,$$
for $|x|\le1$, and $a_1, a_2, a_3, \cdots$ are all positive rational numbers.

Now, by simply substituting $x=-1$ we get
$$1-\sum_1^\infty a_n = \sqrt{1 + (-1)}=0,$$
or
$$\boxed{\sum_1^\infty |(-1)^{n+1}a_n| = 1}$$

On the other hand, if you substitute $x=1$ you get
$$\boxed{\sum_1^\infty (-1)^{n+1}a_n = \sqrt{2}-1}$$
which is not convergent in $\mathbb{Q},$ although it's absolutely convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Or take the finite sequences $l^2_0$ within the square integrable ones $l^2$ and consider the sequence (or the net):
$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}e_k$$
$$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{n}e_n$$