# In a normed space $X$, convergence of $\|y_1\|+\|y_2\|+\cdots$ may not imply convergence of $y_1+y_2+\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Hint to show the veracity of this statement is to consider subspace $Y:=$ the subspace of $l^\infty$ consisting of sequences which have almost all elements equal to zero; and $y_j\in Y$, such that $y_j=(x_n), x_j=\frac 1{j^2}, x_n=0\, \forall n\ne j.$

So clearly $\sum_{i=1}^n \|y_i\|=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac 1{i^2},$ which is convergent.

I think that the series $\sum y_i$ also converges. I claim that the series converges to $(1,1/2^2,1/3^2,\cdots, 1/n^2,\cdots)=:l.$

Clearly, $\|\sum_{i=1}^n y_i-l\|=\|(|y_1-1|,|y_2-\frac 1{2^2}|,\cdots, |y_n-\frac 1{n^2}|, \frac 1{n^2+1},\cdots)\|=\sup (|y_1-1|,|y_2-\frac 1{2^2}|,\cdots, |y_n-\frac 1{n^2}|, \frac 1{n^2+1},\cdots)=\frac 1{n^2+1}\to 0$.

This proves the claim.

Am I missing something here or the hint is correct? How do I prove this statement?

Comment: It converges in $\ell^\infty$ but not in $Y$

Comment: some other counter-examples in this post https://math.stackexchange.com/q/766653/399263

Comment: @CalvinKhor: Thanks a lot. I understand it now.

Comment: @zwim: Thanks a lot. I'll take a look.